# how to add tag on webapi for swagger ui

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

i am learning asp.net webapi. now i add swagger to my asp.net project.

[image]

I noticed that there is a tag filter. but how to add tag to my API action?

Answer (score 1):

When you Generate new Controller for Example **EmployeeController**

and Your routes like this (Example):

Get => /api/Employee/

post => /api/Employee/

put => /api/Employee/{id}

Delete => /api/Employee/{id}

your **Tag is Employee**

[image]

You can see in this [Link](https://code-maze.com/swagger-ui-asp-net-core-web-api/)

or you can Add Your Custom Document Filter as below:

```
public class OrderTagsDocumentFilter: IDocumentFilter {
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, 
               DocumentFilterContext context) {
    swaggerDoc.Tags = swaggerDoc.Tags.OrderBy(x => 
                x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

And add it to your StartUp Class Like Below:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
    Title = "Shoppy.WebApi", Version = "v1"
  });
    c.EnableAnnotations();

    c.DocumentFilter<OrderTagsDocumentFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an `OpenApiTag` attribute on a controller or an action method does the trick.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[OpenApiTag("Temparature")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: This only appears to apply to NSwag (which isn't the default swagger generator in ASP.net it seems).